# Function is returning empty data frame

Tags: python

if I try `update_figure(2019)`, return is a empty data frame
if I try `update_figure('2019')`, return is a desired data frame

I can only give 2019 as input into the query and not "2019".

Any workaround?

```
def update_figure(year):
       df_year = df.loc[df['year'] == year]
       return df_year
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type of your year column is `object` i.e. string, convert it to `int`

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)
```

Before doing that check if you have some empty values in your `year` column. 
I suspect there are empty strings `''`, If yes then use `str.replace` to replace the empty space with the desired integer